# PHP Getting highest value from array (from SQL select)

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

I have 2 tables: **dt_times** and **dt_reports**

**dt_times** contains a list of times and **dt_reports** contains votes (positive/negative) on the associated times.

My code does the following :

- Selects all times before today
- For each of those times - calculates a margin `((positive-negative)/positive)*100`
- The result is stored in an array

After all iterations, here is the var_dump of id => margin

```
array(8) {

    [111]=> int(100)
    [110]=> int(-100)
    [108]=> int(-100)
    [100]=> int(100)
    [97]=> int(100)
    [92]=> int(100)
    [59]=> float(-71.4285714286)
    [58]=> float(-50)

 }
```

I need to select the highest margin, where the id is also the highest. Because you can see that 111, 100, 97 and 92 - all have the same value of a 100.

My code up till now was this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    //Get values for quality
    //calculate margin
    $arr[$row['id']] = $margin;
    $arr2[$margin] = $row['id'];

}

$timeId = $arr2[max($arr)];
```

However, after all loops, $timeId is 92 which is the last id in the array that has value of 100

I think array_keys might be the answer, but for the love of my life, I couldn't figure them out =(

Comment: Why don't you get the average from key and value in your loop?

Comment: Can you post your query as well? Maybe you should prefer to let the database do the work for you.

Comment: You might achieve it with a change in query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort your resulting array by keys with krsort - http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php . It will return the highest key with highest value as the first element.

```
  <?php
   $a = array(10 => 10, 20=>10, 20=>20);
   krsort($a);
   var_dump($a);

  ?>
```

Comment: This won't work, it fails with array(10 => 10, 20=>10, 20=>20, 20=>30, 20=>25)

Comment: @Nelson : Just simply try var_dump the array you gave. How can we store more than one value to the same key?

Comment: Umm, in that case you were right. I assumed it could exist same ids.

Comment: @janenz00 silly question: with `$a = array(12 => 100, 11=>70, 15 => 100, 13=>100  ); ` var_dump returns `array(4) { [15]=> int(100) [13]=> int(100) [12]=> int(100) [11]=> int(70) }` - I only need the first [15] id and its value - how can I get them, so I could use them in my sql statement?

Comment: Disregard my previous comment. It seems that  `$newArray = array_keys($a);
echo $newArray[0];` works! I also figured out exactly how your solution works, so it actually seems to be the right answer!

Comment: @MetalWing - Yes, or  current($a) will give the first element, if you are accessing it for the first time (meaning, you are not in a loop). Another way is list($key, $val) = each($a). The $key and $val will hold the key and value you require.

Answer (score 1):

Start with retrieving the maximum value of the array http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php, then just iterate through the array and find the keys with margins that match that max value.

```
$arr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    //Get values for quality
    //calculate margin
    $arr[$row['id']] = $margin;
}

$max = max($arr);
$highestId = 0;
foreach($arr as $id => $margin){
  if($margin == $max && $id > $highestId){
    $highestId = $id;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by creating a suitable array to be used with [**usort()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) custom compare function, code follows:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['id'] == $b['id']) {
        if ($a['margin'] == $b['margin']) {
           return 0;
        }
        return ($a['margin'] > $b['margin']) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return ($a['id'] > $b['id']) ? -1 : 1;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    //calculate $margin
    //...
    $arr[] = array('margin'=>$margin ,'id'=>$row['id']);
}

usort($arr, 'cmp');

echo 'The highest id with the highest margin is';
echo ' ID: ' . $arr[0]['id'] . ' MARGIN: ' . $arr[0]['margin'];

//Print full sorted classification
foreach($arr as $val) {
   echo 'ID:' . $val['id'] . ' MARG: ' . $val['margin'] . '<br>';
}
```

This solution will give you `$arr` ordered by id, margin from highest to lower, so the first item `$arr[0]` is the highest id and margin, and you can loop the rest of the array to print the full sorted table, not just the highest item.

Comment: Not going to lie, this is the longest and least understood by me solution, but it just works so perfectly and gives me all the data I need and more! Thank You!